# Best material to prevent stainless steel wire abrasion (polyamide coated)

Tags: materials, steel, material-science

I have a 1.5mm diameter wire that must be pulled against the corner of a surface.   The wire is made of stainless steel and coated with polyamide.

What is the ideal material to make corner of the surface in order to:

- reduce wear of the wire (easier to replace the surface) but without being worn out too quickly
- low friction
- ideally easy to machine / source

Thanks!

Comment: I had a look at https://www.makeitfrom.com/ but am not sure how to start evaluating options, and hoped an expert could point me at a few options. :)

Comment: Can you just put an idler pulley there? Even if you need to make a tiny one with a pin or rod.

Comment: Increase the radius of the curvature.  The stainless will cold wok quickly running over a small radius.

Comment: I can't reduce the radius or put a pulley there as the wire must exit from the same point.  Weird design constraint, I know!

Comment: What does cold wok mean?  Google suggests recipes! :)  EDIT: haha, I'm an idiot.  Cold work!

Comment: Can you machine down into that point to accommodate a roller? Because any bearing material you choose needs to be softer than nylon or else the rope will wear away instead but nylon is already pretty soft so the only choice is...nylon.

Comment: What is maximum surface strain ? If over about 0.4 % it will have limited number of cycles to failure.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks, will the polyamide and the nylon wear at the best rate?  Are there materials that will wear faster than the nylon that I could use as a replaceable insert?

Comment: I'll try to calculate it @blacksmith37 - good question!

Comment: 0.07 according to the simulation I set up in Fusion (presuming I did that right).  How did you get the 0.4% threshold?

Comment: @John Nylon *is* a polyamide. I'm essentially saying use the same material that coats the wire because the material that coats the wire is so soft to begin with and anything harder will wear the rope faster than it needs to. I looked into it and it seems teflon is softer than nylon so the teflon would wear preferentially in that case over the rope but it might be too soft. The friction of nylon on nylon is so low to begin with that I don't think the low friction of teflon is that much benefit because teflon is a lot more expensive. You could also try looking into olefin (heatshrink film).

Comment: Thank you DKNugyen - that's really useful advice.  I'll see if I can get some and perform some trials.